# How to set up JBoss 4.2 GA debug configuration in Eclipse IDE (ubuntu)?

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I have a JBoss Debug configuration. It was set up in

> Debug Configuration > Java Application > New

Main Class is set to

> *org.jboss.Main*

VM arguments is set to

> -Xms512m -Xmx3172m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled  -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled  -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m  -Dorg.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=false

Working directory is set to

> /jboss-4.2.1.GA/bin

This configuration works. But how can I run this configuration in JBoss 4.2 GA?

I don't know if the debug configuration set up under the Java Application runs under a Jboss or what. please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

In  jboss/bin open run.conf.sh uncomment this line in

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

which will enable 8787 as debug port

in eclipse rightclick on project click debug as->Remote Java Application->right click->new

enter port as 8787 and host name localhost and click on debug.

you are good to go

Comment: it says "could not detect any running remote java applications." The project is on my local(it was not checkout in SVN using eclipse) as well as my JBoss. Do that matter?

Comment: on jboss start did you see debug port 8787 ?

Comment: I didn't see it at the console.

Comment: are you running your server using run.bat and make sure you have run.conf in your  run.bat file

Comment: I'm running JBoss server on the server tab(Java EE perspective) of the Eclipse IDE. I have run.bat and run.conf, should I reference run.conf inside run.bat?

Comment: if you run jboss inside eclipse you can use Debug As > Debug on Server-next->enter jboss installation directory--->finish

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115535/discussion-between-manoj-krishna-and-zbryan).